# Can I specify the width of a pdf generated using MPDF

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

Is it possible to set the width of the page that I'm doing or do it have a standard width for all the generated pages ?

I'm using a layout with `css` files with a wrapper that have a specific width, but when the PDF is generated the width of the file is not the width I specified in the css.

Do I have to make the width smaller or can I specify it when the document is created as a param ?

Comment: Always do some research. Always STFW and RTFM then ask

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the mpdf [documentation](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=184) yielded

```
new mPDF('', 'Letter', 0, '', 12.7, 12.7, 14, 12.7, 8, 8);
```

PDF files need to have a paper page width specified - so that is what you have to give it.
You can give it a width specified in mm by replacing `'Letter'` with `array(x, y)`.